# How can I make a variable have different value for different tab

Tags: vim

I'm trying to display the git branch in my status line and I have these code:

```
function! GitBranch()
    let current_path = expand('%:p:h')
    let cd = "cd " . current_path
    let branch = system(cd . "&& git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null | tr -d '\n'")
    return strlen(branch) > 0 ? '  '. branch . ' ' : ''
endfunction

" Customize status line
set statusline=
set statusline+=%#Normal#
set statusline+=%=
set statusline+=%#CursorColumn#
set statusline+=%{GitBranch()}
set statusline+=%#Normal#
set statusline+=\ 
set statusline+=\%y
set statusline+=\ %p%%
set statusline+=\ %l:%c
set statusline+=\
```

Now it calls the function GitBranch() every time I input something, which makes it quite laggy. So I decide to put the branch name in a variable instead of calling the function every time.

```
let status_git = GitBranch()
...
...
set statusline+=%{status_git}
```

Now the question is, if I open a new tab, the variable won't change. So all tabs have the same branch name. Is there any way I can fix this?

I know there's some good plugins like Vim-airline which can do this perfectly. I just want to do this in my way.

Comment: Are you sure `GitBranch()` returns different results for different tabs?

Comment: If I directly use the function instead of store its value in a variable, then yes.

Answer (score 2):

You set the value for `status_git` once and it's never changed after that. You need to recalculate it for every new tab in some autocommand; `BufReadPre`, I think.

To set variable local for a buffer use prefix `b:`.

```
autocmd! BufReadPre let b:status_git = GitBranch()
```